# Why does super()() not do the same as super().__init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I have been wondering this for a while now, and I hope this isn't a stupid question with an obvious answer I'm not realizing: Why can't I just call the `__init__` method of `super()` like `super()()`? I have to call the method like this instead: `super().__init__()`

Here is an example that gets a `TypeError: 'super' object is not callable` error when I run it (specifically on line 6 that comes from line 3 in `__init__`):

```
class My_Int(int):
    def __init__(self,value,extr_data=None):
        super()(value)
        self.extr_data=extr_data

x=My_Int(3)
```

Doesn't `super()` get the inherited class `int` making `super()(value)` the same as `int(value)`?

Furthermore, why can't I use the `len` function with `super()` when inheriting from the class `list`? Doesn't `len()` do the same as `__len__()`?

```
class My_List(list):
    def some_method1(self):
        print(len(super()))

    def some_method2(self):
        print(super().__len__())

x=My_List((1,2,3,4))

x.some_method2()
x.some_method1()
```

This example prints 4 and then an error as expected. Here is the output exactly:

```
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    x.some_method1()
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 3, in some_method1
    print(len(super()))
TypeError: object of type 'super' has no len()
```

Notice I called `some_method2` before calling `some_method1` (sorry for the confusion).

Am I missing something obvious here?

- P.S. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: "Doesn't super() get the inherited class int" - no, and "making super()(value) the same as int(value)" - calling `int(value)` wouldn't do what you want either.

Comment: `super()()` creates a new instance of the superclass. The purpose of `super().__init__()` is to call the parent's init method on the current instance.

Comment: @Barmar: No, `super()()` raises a TypeError.

Comment: So would int.__init__(value) do what I would expect? @user2357112

Comment: I'm on my phone so i can't easily give a detailed answer here, but contrary to other languages you might know, `super()` is not simply a stand-in for the instance itself cast to its parent class. `len(super())` doesn't make any sense because the `super` object is something else entirely, responsible for navigating the method resolution order of an object given it's class. In Python 2 this was made a little more explicit in that you had to pass it two arguments like `super(cls, self)` but Python 3 added syntactic sugar to make this automatic for the most "obvious" case.

Comment: Yeah, isn't creating a new instance of a class what init does? @Barmar

Comment: No. The instance is already created, it's passed as the `self` argument. `__init__` initializes it by setting attributes.

Comment: @user18798042 no `__init__` does not create a new instance. It merely initializes the instance once it's created. That's why `__init__` gets `self` as an argument. `self` is already an instance of that class. So where did that `self` come from? (Hint: look into `__new__`)

Comment: I've always wondered why `__init__` got the `self` argument as well. @Iguananaut

Comment: I realized another reason you might have this question is, if `super().__len__` seems to exist why doesn't it support the `len()` protocol like other things that define `__len__`? To answer that thoroughly goes a bit deep but for a quick answer it's because (most) attribute lookups on `super` go through the internal equivalent of `__getattr__`. Iff it's an attribute not found on the `super` object itself, it calls special code to look that attribute up through the MRO of the object proxied by `super()`. For `len()` to work on the `super` itself its type would have to have a `__len__` slot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`super()` objects can't intercept most special method calls, because they bypass the instance and look up the method on the type directly, and they don't want to implement all the special methods when many of them won't apply for any given usage. This case gets weirder, `super()()` would try to lookup a `__call__` method on the `super` type itself, and pass it the `super` instance.

They don't do this because it's ambiguous, and not particularly explicit. Does `super()()` mean invoke the super class's `__init__`? Its `__call__`? What if we're in a `__new__` method, do you invoke `__new__`, `__init__` or both? Does this mean all `super` uses must implicitly know which method they're called in (even more magical than knowing the class they were defined in and the `self` passed when constructed with zero arguments)?

Rather than deal with all this, and to avoid implementing all the special methods on `super` just so it can delegate them *if* they exist on the instance in question, they required you to explicitly specify the special method you intend to call.